# NodeJS sockets initialized as unpaused?

Tags: node.js

A net.Socket object in NodeJS is a Readable Stream, however one note in the docs got me concerned:

For the `Net.Socket` `'data'` event, the [docs say](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_data)

> Note that the **data will be lost** if there is no listener when a `Socket` emits a `'data'` event.

That seems to imply a Socket is returned to the calling script in "flowing-mode" and already un-paused? However, for a generic Readable Stream, the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) for the `'data'` event says

> If you attach a `data` event listener, then it will switch the stream into flowing mode, and data will be passed to your handler as soon as it is available.

That "If" seems to imply if you wait a bit to bind to the `'data'` event, the stream will wait for you, and if you intentionally want to miss the `'data'` events, the [example](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume) in the `resume()` method seems to indicate you must call the `resume()` method to start the flow of data.

My concern is that when working with a `net.Server`, when you receive a `net.Socket` as part of a `'connection'` event, is it imperative that you start handling the `'data`' events right away since it's already opened? Meaning if I do:

```
var s = new net.Server();
s.on('connection', function(socket) {
  // Do some lengthy setup process here, blocking execution for a few seconds...
  socket.on('data', function(d) { console.log(d); });
});
s.listen(8080);
```

Meaning not bind to the `'data'` event right away, I could lose data? So is this a more robust way to handle incoming connections if you have a lengthy setup required for each one?

```
var s = new net.Server();
s.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.pause(); // Not ready for you yet!

  // Do some lengthy setup process here, blocking execution for a few seconds...

  socket.on('data', function(d) { console.log(d); });
  socket.resume(); // Okay, go!
});
s.listen(8080);
```

Anyone have experience working with listening on raw socket streams to know if this data loss is an issue?

I'm hoping this is an instance where the Net.Socket documentation wasn't updated since v0.10, since the [stream documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_compatibility_with_older_node_versions) has a section that mentions `'data'` events started emitting right away in versions prior to 0.10. Were TCP sockets properly updated to not start emitting `'data'` packets right away, and the  documentation not updated appropriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the docs flaw. Here is an example:

```
var net = require('net')
var server = net.createServer(onConnection)

function onConnection (socket) {
  console.log('onConnection')

  setTimeout(startReading, 1000)

  function startReading () {
    socket.on('data', read)
    socket.on('end', stopReading)
  }

  function stopReading () {
    socket.removeListener('data', read)
    socket.removeListener('end', stopReading)
  }
}

function read (data) {
  console.log('Received: ' + data.toString('utf8'))
}

server.listen(1234, onListening)

function onListening () {
  console.log('onListening')
  net.connect(1234, onConnect)
}

function onConnect () {
  console.log('onConnect')
  this.write('1')
  this.write('2')
  this.write('3')
  this.write('4')
  this.write('5')
  this.write('6')
}
```

All the data is received. If you explicitly `resume()` socket, you will lose it.

Also, if you do your "lengthy" setup in a blocking manner (which you shouldn't) you can't lose any IO as it has no chance to be processed, so no events will be emitted.